# Cloning github repo recursive using https instead of ssh

Tags: git, github

There is a github repo A that has a submodule repo B. Both A & B are public, so anyone can clone them with `git clone` or just download zip.

In A's `.gitmodules` reference to B is specified via ssh connection string

```
url = git@github.com:PersonB/B.git
```

If I run `git clone A --recursive` from local machine it works fine, because my ssh keys are on github. However, I need this to run on a server, actually, multiple servers, and not by me. So there is no way that all these ssh keys are added to someone's github account. If I run `git clone A --recursive` from a server, I get the good old

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

First option here is to ask developer A to change `url` in `.gitmodules`, but, this is probably not the only such repo. Second option is to rewrite `.gitmodules` myself after shallow cloning and then do submodule update. Is there any nicer way?